# Import all type of files (cvs, xls, txt) to one master excel file from a folder directory

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a macro that needs to select any folder I want and import every type of file within that folder that's cvs, xls, txt and put them all into 1 workbook (not sheet). So all the tabs imported would be there. Right now the code can take in only 1 type. I tried changing the code below to:

```
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.csv, *.xls,*.txt")
```

but nothing happened.

The macro below has a fixed directory path right now but I would like to have a dialog box pop up which allows me to be flexible in selecting any folder I want to import my files from. Here's what I got so far, but please modify it or make a new one that best works.

```
Sub Input_Sheets()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Dim WrdArray() As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "C:\Users\ktam\Desktop\New folder\"

'Switch to the preferred type the folders hold. (It cannot hold 2 types)
'fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.csv")

'As long as the file name is found in the folder, import the file.
Do While fileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName) 'Opens a random file from the folder
    'WrdArray() = Split(fileName, ".")

    For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
    'Workbooks(fileName).ActiveSheet.Name = WrdArray(0) '0 Puts in the name of the document

                total = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(total)
    Next sheet

Workbooks(fileName).Close
fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox "Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `*.*` and filter out the types you want as you loop through by checking the extension...

Comment: Excellent Tim! That takes care of importing everything I want to the document. Now only if I can select it from any folder I chose.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/browsefolder.aspx see the last function on the page

Answer (score 0):

I have this code that's really useful for looping within a folder and loading the files into an array based on the file names:

```
Global sfolder As String

sub file_merger()

file = Dir(folderchooser)

dim trackerfiles(1 to 500) as variant

counter = 1

Do While file <> ""

    if instr(1,file,".xlsx") > 0 or instr(1,file,".csv") > 0 then   


    trackerfiles(counter) = sfolder & "\" & file
    file = Dir()
    counter = counter + 1

    If file = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    End if

Loop


end sub

Function folderchooser() As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    sfolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

folderchooser = sfolder & "\"

End Function
```

You could use it load into an array and then write your own code to import the files into your workbook (the tricky part is looping through the folder).